# Is SplashScreen not DPI aware?

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen, dpi

I don't use my App.xaml as `ApplicationDefinition`.
Instead, I provide my own `Main()`:

```
public static SplashScreen StaticSplash = new SplashScreen("/Splash.png");

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StaticSplash.Show(autoClose: false, topMost: true);

    //... more code

    App application = new App();
    application.InitializeComponent();
    application.Run();
}
```

In my `App`s `Startup` event I get rid of my `SplashScreen` and show a `Window` mimicking splash-screen behaviour with a `ProgressBar`:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    //the following SplashScreen class is a Window
    UI.SplashScreen.SplashScreen sScr = new UI.SplashScreen.SplashScreen();
    sScr.ProgressBar.Maximum = 1d;
    sScr.Show();
    Program.StaticSplash.Close(new TimeSpan(0));

    //... even more code
}
```

This works quite well, but the problem is the scaling of the first `SplashScreen` (`StaticSplash` in my code):
My monitor runs at 3840x2160px, 175% DPI.
The image (`new SplashScreen("/Splash.png")`) is 400x200 px.
The splash-screen mimicking Window is set to `Width="400" Height="225"` (ProgressBar is 25px high).

The Window gets scaled correctly: when taking a screenshot and measuring with some graphics program it's 700x394px, 175% of the original 400x225px.

The image I provide to the `SplashScreen` class gets not scaled. It remains at true 400x200px.

Is there any chance to make the first `SplashScreen` dpi aware or scale it manually, preferably as the very first thing in `Main()`?

Answer (score 0):

You got the problem backwards, the problem is that it *is* dpi-aware.  If it wasn't then DPI virtualization would rescale the window and its content by 175%.  Which also enlarges the bitmap.  Tends to be objectionable, it gets fuzzy.

But a WPF app is dpi-aware, the module constructor of PresentationCore calls SetProcessDPIAware().  Which makes the window bigger by 175%.  But not the bitmap, you still see it at 400x200 pixels.  Not fuzzy, one pixel in the bitmap maps to one display pixel, just what you want out of a dpi-aware app.  But of course now too small to fit the window.

You'll have to resize it yourself.  Which of course reproduces the fuzziness that DPI virtualization produces.  Not getting the fuzzies does require bitmaps that are designed to match the dpi.  Perhaps not that much to fret about for a splash screen, just pick a design without fine detail and no text.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks for the explanation. Rescaling the image programmatically brings more problems, especially giving the `SplashScreen` class a programmatically generated bitmap. Sure, another possibility is to embed different sizes of the image and choose one... I have to make up my mind if it's worth the effort.